# Is there a difference in meaning between "go to the seaside" and "go to the sea"?

Tags: difference, phrase-choice

Let's say I am going on vacation. And I am planing to spend my vacation by the sea. Is there any difference between the following sentences?

> I am going **to the seaside**.
>
> I am going **to the sea**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first is standard. You say you are planning to spend your vacation *by* the sea. The seaside is by the sea. So you are going to the seaside. 'Seaside towns' are towns by the sea.

If you are playing on a sandy beach and have built a castle, the moat will need to be filled with water. Before toddling to the water's edge with your bucket you might tell your playmates,

**"I'm going to the sea."**

Only when we are going right to the water's edge do we use that expression.

By the way, if you say you are ***going to sea*** it means you are about to sail away for a long period; or that you're joining the navy or becoming a pirate.

Comment: +1 I love this answer. *"you're joining the navy or becoming a pirate"*, yes that's right!